# Finding the radius of an arc

Tags: geometry

So for a summer project I need to measure the diameter of corneas present in photographs of babies.  Thus, parts of the "circle" that is the cornea is obstructed.  How can I accurately determine the diameter of this circle if I don't have the full circle to work with?  I know there are ways to find the center of the circle using right triangles or chords but I the top and bottom of the circle are cut off due to our natural eye lid resting position.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering the rephrased question "How do I measure the radius use to draw out the arc of a circle?"

Pick three points on the arc. Connect two lines between them (preferably "in order") and draw the midpoint perpendicular line from each of these. Where these two perpendicular lines meet will give you the center of the circle and will allow to you measure the radius.

Comment: Could you provide a picture example to show how to do this.  Please keep in mind that the tops and bottoms of my circles are cut off

Comment: @DivyaT, work out the picture based on what I've written. Also--it doesn't matter how much of the circle is covered. As long is there is some portion of the circling there, an arc, then this is possible.

Comment: Am I drawing two lines for each point? Or if I have points A,B,C am I drawing a line from A to B and B to C? Do the points need to be on opposite sides of the circle?  What if they are all concentrated on the left part of the circle

Comment: @DivyaT: here is an example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/503888/Transfer/fig.png

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If I understand your question correctly this should be helpful:

$$ r = \frac{h}{2} + \frac{w^2}{8 * h}$$